# Counting how many date ranges contain a given date

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of people and their birth dates (these are boy scouts). I want to have a list of dates (upcoming ones), and be able to find out how many of these scouts are 12-13 years old on all of these dates...

Here is what I mean:

```
Name:           Birthdate         Turns 12 on:        Turns 14 on:
John            1/2/1999          1/2/2011            1/2/2013
Joe             2/5/2000          2/5/2012            2/5/2014
Jack            3/2/2001          3/2/2013            3/2/2015
Jim             4/2/2002          4/2/2014            4/2/2016
```

Now I would like to have a list of dates, and how many scouts are in the correct range on that date:

```
Date:           Scouts:
1/1/2013        3
1/7/2013        2
```

Basically, I want the formula under "Scouts" to grab the date next to it, and find out how many scouts are 12 and 13 on that date.

I've tried a few things, including this:

```
=COUNTIFS(H2:H56,H2>F2,H2:H56,H2<G2)
```

where H is the date that I am checking against, and F is the "Turns 12 on" date, and G is the "Turns 14 on" date.

I am not overly experienced in excel, so even pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will look it over, however, I am looking for a little bit of advanced help.

Comment: Having perused the link that you placed there, I thank you for your condescension, and wonder how that link applies to the question I asked? Absolutely nothing there that I did not know, and either you expect everyone asking for help to already know the answer to the question, or you are not understanding the question yourself, and therefore not understanding why someone inexperienced would as it to a super user forum. I wonder which it is?

Comment: @Silas remember everyone here is trying to help, some help better than others, but remain calm. The link contains some general information, that didn't help you. Don't panic and ask the poster where the relevant information is.

Comment: Your COUNTIF seems right, but I think you have the columns mixed up.

Comment: Doktoro - you are correct, and I apologize to you if I have flown off the handle prematurely. If it turns out that the link was meant to be useful, I will happily apologize to the original commenter. In that vein, @Sickest, would you please inform me as to what part of the information in that link will help me answer my question?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard, columns mixed up? Possibly. Is my logic incorrect? The value in H has to be greater than the value in F (is he at least 12) and the value in H has to be less than the value in G (is he at least 14).

Comment: My logic is the following, as written: Count if: in the range of birthdates, the **date you selected** is greater than the "Turns 12 on:" AND in the range of birthdates, the **date you selected** is lower than the "Turns 14 on:

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - that is how I see the logic as well, and how it has been written, and yet it always comes up with zero, even when I know it SHOULD be non-zero.

Comment: OK - so I've simplified the problem a bit, I think. Column B is the birth date, and column H is the column for arbitrary dates. So this formula should work: =COUNTIF(H2:H56,H2>B2), and yet it comes up with Zero. I know I'm just missing something simple, as EVERY SINGLE DATE in column H is larger than any date in column B.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard, Basically - I'm trying to do this - wording it a little bit better: Count if: in the range of birth dates, the chosen arbitrary date is larger than ANY birth date. This does not appear to work. (Also, to reflect that, the formula was changed to: =COUNTIF(B2:B56,H2>B2) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, in case someone needs to know the same thing...

I think @DoktoroReichard was correct - I was looking a little bit backwards.

=COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$51,"<="&H2, $G$2:$G$51, ">"&H2)

Column F is the "Turns 12 on" date, Column G is the "Turns 14 on" date, and column H is an arbitrary date.

This basically says:

Count if: For all values in the "turns 12 on" date, the chosen date is greater than or equal to AND for all values in the "Turns 14 on" date, the chosen date is less than.

It now calculates the number of scouts that will be 12 or 13 on any given date.

I also used the dollar signs so that I could use this formula to fill out a large number of arbitrary dates.

Comment: I gave you that link before your question was edited and become more complex, your question at first was very vague and i thought you really didn't understand the concept of formulas including if statements, it wasn't specifically supposed to give an answer, but a nudge you to maybe figure it on your own (my thinking it was a simple excel question) which now clearly it is not. try making your question as detailed as possible to start with and you'll get faster help.

Comment: @Sickest, thank you for your explanation. In the future, it would probably be more useful to ask for clarification rather than posting a very simplistic link and downvoting. To be fair, the question did not become more complex when I edited it - the only thing added was the formula that I had tried that did not work. I apologize for my reaction, and will attempt to refrain from such in the future.